# A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo'. > Project with path ':expo-modules-core' could not be found in project ':expo'

Tags: react-native, gradle, expo, build.gradle

I can't successfully build my app at the moment due to this error. I haven't been able to find a fix for it. I've noticed that there are two other identical questions on stackoverflow that don't seem to have been answered.

The error gets thrown in this file:

```
...\myProject\node_modules\expo\android\build.gradle' line: 39
```

Can anyone help? Happy to provide any part of my project on here in order to solve it, just let me know what to post.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for downvoting a question! Helpful! Please let me know how I can improve it/why it deserves to be downvoted!

Answer (score 3):

Add `include ':expo-modules-core'` to your `settings.gradle` file in `android` folder